# "Need Help In Php script" How to avoid sending emails from default server email address

Tags: php, function, email

I am using the below script to send emails from my webpage used as " refer a friend " which can be used to send emails to friends to refer the site. This works fine. But one problem, Friend who receives the email will notice that the received from emails shows the server default email address with nameservers. I want the received email to show my new account created with info@example.com

```
(This is the php script)

$status = "OK"; 
$msg=""; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$y_email=$_POST['y_email']; 
$y_name=$_POST['y_name']; 

$f_email=$_POST['f_email']; 
$f_name=$_POST['f_name']; 
$y_msg=$_POST['y_msg']; 
if(substr_count($y_email,"@") > 1 or substr_count($f_email,"@") > 1){ 
$msg .="Use only one email address<br />"; 
$status= "NOTOK"; 
} 
if (!stristr($y_email,"@") OR !stristr($y_email,".")) { // checking your email 
$msg .="Your email address is not correct<br />"; 
$status= "NOTOK";} 
if (strlen($y_name) <2 ) { // checking your name 
$msg .="Please enter your name<br />"; 
$status= "NOTOK";} 
if (!stristr($f_email,"@") OR !stristr($f_email,".")) { // checking friends email 
$msg .="Your Friends address is not correct<br />"; 
$status= "NOTOK";} 
if (strlen($f_name) <2 ) { // checking freinds name 
$msg .="Please enter your friend's name<br />"; 
$status= "NOTOK";} 

if($status=="OK"){ // all validation passed 

/////////// Sending the message starts here ////////////// 
$ref=@$HTTP_REFERER; 
/////Message at the top of the page showing the url//// 
$header_message = ""; 
/// Body message prepared with the message entered by the user //// 
$body_message =$header_message." ".$y_msg." "; 
$body_message .="Hi $f_name wants you to know about this great service!"; 
//// Mail posting part starts here ///////// 
$headers=""; 
//$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1n".$headers; 
// Un comment the above line to send mail in html format 
$headers4=$y_email; // Change this to change from address 
$headers.="Reply-to: $headers4n"; 
$headers .= "From: $headers4n"; 
$headers .= "Errors-to: $headers4n"; 
$subject="Hello!"; 
mail($f_email,$subject,$body_message,$headers); 
////// Mail posting ends here /////////// 

}
}




(form)

 <form action="" method="post" id="refer-friend"> 
<strong style="font-size:12px">Your Full Name</strong> 
<br />
<input name="y_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['y_name'])) ?>" type="text" />
<br />
<strong style="font-size:12px">Your Email</strong>
<br />
<input name="y_email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['y_email']))?>" type="text" /> 

<br />
<br />
<br />

<strong style="font-size:12px">Your Friends Name</strong>
<br />
<input name="f_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['f_name']))?>" type="text" />
<br />
<strong style="font-size:12px">your Friends Email</strong>
<br />
<input name="f_email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['f_email']))?>" type="text" />
<br />
    <br />

<p>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button orange">Send Request</button>
                </p> 
</form>
```

Comment: No need to do this. Most ISP's will mark your messages as spam. Leave it as server's email address

Comment: What is the value of $headers4n, I am seeing the variable $headers4 not $headers4n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this in your code.

```
 $headers .= 'From: info@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            $headers = "From: <$y_email>\n";

        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 

        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, But emails says that the email may not have sent from gmail.